# What is the best way to unify backend and frontend dates, times?

Tags: laravel, reactjs, api, date, time

I'm working on a project where back-end API is built on Laravel and the front-end is developed on ReactJS. So my question is what would be the best way to share date and time from back-end to the front-end? The date and time is really important because it is a lottery app and lottery countdowns should always show the same time for all users despite the date and time set on their computer. Also, I'm making some data filtrations dependent on time.

The solution I thought about is to make endpoint for current servers date and time and every time when React fetches lotteries also fetch the current time on the server. But I don't think it's a good solution, could someone suggest a better one?

Comment: How it is related to ReactJS?

Answer (score 2):

Store Dates as UTC timestamps (numbers) or UTC dates (date/datetime in your backend). In Javascript, those UTC timestamps will be converted to local time. Or you could use something like moment if you really need to display timezones based on logged-in user preferences.

Remember, you can convert any Date from the client to UTC with `date.getTime()` that returns a timestamp in case you need to create something from the client.

In the end, getting your DB to store dates as UTC is the only thing that matters!

Answer (score 0):

Both the client and server should do their own time sync with a network clock. But the server should ignore any times recorded on the client as they can be faked.

Times should be recorded on data when they are received on the server. That way there is never an issue about time synchronisation between client and server. Time are usually recorded in the DB in UTC time, and then offset on the client. Any server side rendering in your Laravel code will need to consider the time zone of the front end requesting the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't fully understand, are your suggesting to use NTP? Maybe you could show an example? @Mikkel

Comment: Both desktops and servers should be set up to use NTP already (assuming they were set up right). What I'm saying is, make the server the only arbiter of times. So any time stamp should be allocated on the server, not the client. This will save any challenges to do with slightly different times on client machines